Will there be forgiveness in the age to come?
During his sermon regarding the unforgivable sin, Jesus did state that people who blaspheme the Holy Spirit will not be forgiven in this age or in the age to come which implies that there will be forgiveness on forgivable sins in that age.
Mathew 12:32

whoever speaks against the Holy Spirit will not be forgiven, either in this age or in the age to come,"

From that context, it looks as if there will be forgiveness which will be limited to sins that do not make someone guilty of eternal damnation, why does God forgive men in the age to come?

The argument does not follow. Stating that a particular sin is so grievous and culpable that it will never be forgiven in the future age does not imply that other sins will be. Multipe other scriptures make this clear.

@NigelJ, or in the age to come is inclusive and comparative , this age and  the other age have one thing in common, forgiveness, the verse clearly shows that there will be forgiveness in the age to come and hence the verse I will show mercy to whom I will

The expression "the age to come", or more accurately, "the coming age" has been understood in Matt 12:32 in two ways:

the Christain dispensation is the "coming age" vs the Jewish (then current) Jewish age.  This is the view of commentators such as Ellicott, Macknight
Proverbial expression verging on hyperbole for something that would never be done.  This is the view of Benson and probably Barnes

[This means that Jesus did NOT imply anything about forgiveness in hell or heaven as the coming age.]
In my view, both are equally likely meanings.  In either case, the force and meaning of Jesus' statement is clear - blasphemy against the holy Spirit will never be forgiven.

There will be forgiveness though otherwise Jesus wouldn't have compared this age to the age to come
